# MFC CDateTimeCtrl::SetMonthCalColor doesn't work

Tags: mfc

**in header file:**

`class CTyDate : public CDateTimeCtrl`

**in cpp file:**

```
void CTyDate::PreSubclassWindow()
{
    CDateTimeCtrl::PreSubclassWindow();
    int n1 = 0;
    n1 = SetMonthCalColor(MCSC_TITLEBK, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    n1 = SetMonthCalColor(MCSC_MONTHBK, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    n1 = SetMonthCalColor(MCSC_TEXT, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    n1 = SetMonthCalColor(MCSC_TITLETEXT, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    n1 = SetMonthCalColor(MCSC_BACKGROUND, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    n1 = SetMonthCalColor(MCSC_TRAILINGTEXT, RGB(255, 0, 0));
}
```

I make a new class to owner draw this CDateTimeCtrl. I make sure this new class was bind correct and the function CTyDate::PreSubclassWindow() already run into.But nothing happened,the view of DateTimeCtrl was same as before.

Comment: `SetMonthCalColor` (only) changes the styles of the month dropdown, in your case it will draw an all-red box when you click the down arrow. If that's not what you are seeing then the problem is in the code that hooks `CTyDate` to the actual instance of the control, which you have not posted. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In the function you are responding to the `DTN_DROPDOWN` message of your `CTyDate` control, you have to do `::SetWindowTheme(GetMonthCalCtrl()->GetSafeHwnd(), L" ", L" ");` Then all colors will begin to work right as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up to use this function,it not work any more in win10.I implement my custom draw by WM_PAINT.Although I need to wrote more code,but Finary it work well;

[image]